# Generic type is overridden by inheritance in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a class that contains a generic data type.

```dart
class Buck<E> {
  List<E> list;
  Buck({
    required this.list,
  });
}
```

Then, I created a class and a subclass:

```
class SomeThing {}
class SomethingOther extends SomeThing {}
```

I created an object `Buck` with `E` is `SomeThing` class.

```
var buck = Buck<SomeThing>(list: List<SomeThing>.empty());
```

At this point, I assumed that the type of `buck.list` is `List<SomeThing>`. Then, I assign it with `List<SomethingOther>`.

```
buck.list = List<SomethingOther>.empty();
```

At this point, there is nothing unusual. I assume that type of `buck.list` is still `List<SomeThing>`.
However, when I try to add `SomeThing` object to `buck.list`, I get an error:

```
buck.list.add(SomeThing()); // this will be error
```

Here is the complete code:

```
void main() {
  var buck = Buck<SomeThing>(list: List<SomeThing>.empty());
  buck.list = List<SomethingOther>.empty();
  buck.list.add(SomeThing());
}

class Buck<E> {
  List<E> list;
  Buck({
    required this.list,
  });
}

class SomeThing {}
class SomethingOther extends SomeThing {}
```

Why does this happen? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I believe the type of `buck.list` is `List<SomeThing>`, but the list you assigned is of type `List<SomeThingOther>`. That is, the underlying object still retains its real type, it's not erased as it would be in Java for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`, then Dart also treats `Generic<Derived>` to be a subtype of `Generic<Base>`.  Consequently, a `Generic<Derived>` is assignable to (or returnable as) a `Generic<Base>`.

For most generics, that isn't a problem, and it usually provides convenience.  For collections, it can lead to the problem you encountered. A `List<Derived>` can store *only* `Derived` elements.  Therefore assigning a `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>` is *not* actually safe if code later tries to add other `Base` elements.

It's unfortunate.

To avoid this, you should ensure that you construct a `List<Base>` (which in your example, is `List<Something>`), even if it's initialized with `Derived` (`SomethingOther` in your case) elements.  For example:

```dart
var list = <Something>[SomethingOther(), SomethingOther()];
var buck = Buck(list: list);
```

For better protection, you can make `Buck` create its own internal copy of the input `List`, and that way it can ensure that it always has exactly a `List<Something>` and not a `List<SomethingOther>`:

```dart
class Buck<E> {
  List<E> _list = <E>[];

  List<E> get list => _list;

  set list(List<E> newList) {
    _list.clear();
    _list.addAll(newList);
  }

  Buck({required List<E> list}) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Also see:

- [Is Dart type system sound?](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1461)
- [List runtime subtyping error](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1581)