# Why does casting in Dart do not work when extending a class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following the clean architecture by using `Entities` and `Models` but when i tried to loop through list of `Entities` and modify them i got this error `Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'MyEntity': type 'MyEntity' is not a subtype of type 'MyModel'.

I made a simple code that demonstrate the problem:

```
class MyEntity {
  final String id;
  const MyEntity({
    required this.id,
  });
  MyEntity copyWith({
    String? id,
  }) {
    return MyEntity(
      id: id ?? this.id,
    );
  }
}
class MyModel extends MyEntity {
  const MyModel({
    required super.id,
  });
  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return MyModel(
      id: map['id'] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
void main() {
    final List<MyModel> modelsList = [
      MyModel.fromJson({'id': '0'}),
      MyModel.fromJson({'id': '1'}),
      MyModel.fromJson({'id': '2'}),
    ];
  final List<MyEntity> entitiesList = modelsList;
    for (var i = 0; i < entitiesList.length; i++) {
       entitiesList[i] = entitiesList[i].copyWith(id: '99'); 
    }
}
```

I tried to run the code but i get the error above
`Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'MyEntity': type 'MyEntity' is not a subtype of type 'MyModel'`

The example work fine when i replace

```
final List<MyEntity> entitiesList = modelsList;
```

By

```
final List<MyEntity> entitiesList = List<MyEntity>.from(modelsList);
```

I don't understand why it didn't work even thought list is already defined as `List<MyEntity>`

Comment: `final List<MyEntity> entitiesList = modelsList;` does not create a new `List` object.  It just creates another reference to the existing `List<MyModel>` object, and that object expects `MyModel` elements.  Additionally, if you want `copyWith` to return new `MyModel` instances, you need to override it.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes i agree, but the `MyModel` is already extending `MyEntity`. This is weird, How  can you use the `clean architecture` if you'll have to deal with the `Models` inside the domain and presentation layers, you know what i mean. Because if i do this `final List<MyEntity> entitiesList = UserEntity...();` inside the presentation layer but still can deal with `entitiesList` as `List<MyEntity>`. it doesn't make sense

Comment: No.  If you agreed, you would understand that there is nothing weird going on.  You construct instances of the base class and try to add them to a collection that requires instances of the derived class.  The objects you're inserting are not derived objects, so the downcast fails.

Comment: And if you want a `List<MyEntity>` that accepts any `MyEntity` element, you must construct it as a `List<MyEntity>`.  As I said, your original assignment does not create a new `List` object.

Comment: The `List<MyEntity>` type annotation when declaring `entitiesList` does not cast the list, it only lets analyzer to accept what's being assigned on the right-hand side. Sure `MyModel` is acceptable as an element of a list of `MyEntity`, but the underlying list object is still a `List<MyModel>`.

Answer (score 1):

(Elaborating on my comments with code.)

First, I'm going to use `Base` and `Derived` instead of `MyEntity` and `MyModel` respectively so that the class relationship is self-documenting, so that I don't accidentally mix them up, and so that it's more applicable to other readers.

You basically have:

> ```dart
> final List<Derived> derivedList = [...];
> final List<Base> baseList = derivedList;
> ```

That creates a single `List<Derived>` object that is referenced by both `derivedList` and `baseList`.  That's probably not what you intended.

Dart treats `Generic<Derived>` to be a subtype of `Generic<Base>` and therefore allows `Generic<Derived>` to be used where a `Generic<Base>` is expected without any explicit cast.  In most cases this is convenient, but it is potentially unsafe, particularly for generic collections and this situation. (Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76223257/.)

`baseList` has a *static* type of `List<Base>`, but the object it refers to has a *runtime* type of `List<Derived>`.  Attempting to add `Base` objects to a `List<Derived>` is potentially unsafe since not every `Base` object is a `Derived`.  Because `baseList` has a static type of `List<Base>`, the static analyzer cannot detect the type error, and you therefore instead end up with a type error at runtime.

Additionally, the `Base` class has a `copyWith` implementation that is not overridden by the `Derived` class.  Consequently, calling `copyWith` on a `Derived` object will [*slice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) that object and return a new `Base` object that is *not* a `Derived`.  That's probably not what you want.

To fix your problem, you can do one (or ideally both) of:

- Actually make `baseList` a *separate* `List<Base>` object.  There are various ways to do that.  For example:

  ```dart
  var baseList = <Base>[...derivedList];
  ```

  or

  ```dart
  var baseList = List<Base>.of(derivedList);
  ```

  But I'd use collection-`for`:

  ```dart
  var baseList = <Base>[
    for (var element in derivedList) element.copyWith(id: '99'),
  ];
  ```
- Make `Derived` override `copyWith` to prevent object slicing:

  ```dart
  class Base {
    @mustBeOverridden
    Base copyWith({
      String? id,
    }) {
      return Base(...);
    }
  }

  class Derived extends Base {
    @override
    Derived copyWith({
      String? id,
    }) {
      return Derived(...);
    }
  }
  ```